# Does it make sense to implement OAuth for a 2 party system?

Tags: oauth

I'm under the impression that OAuth is for authentication between three parties. Does it make sense to implement OAuth in a context where there is just a client and server.

We have a server, and a client (HTML/javascript). Currently we authenticate via the normal "post credentials to server, get a cookie, use cookie to authenticate all subsequent requests" method. Will implementing OAuth be a benefit in this situation?

Comment: I'd go with OpenID under these circumstances.

Comment: @GaryRowe: OpenID is simpler, but the basic structure that one service uses identity proven by another service remains.

Answer (score 2):

Oauth supports different Grant Types for the differing communications you're asking about.

Here is an example in a PHP library , of a  different grant type or two:

**Client Credentials Grant Type** Trusted Clients and UnTrusted Clients

The `Client Credentials` grant type is used when the client is requesting access to protected resources under its control (i.e. there is no third party).

```
# using HTTP Basic Authentication
$ curl -u TestClient:TestSecret https://api.mysite.com/token -d 'grant_type=client_credentials'

# using POST Body
$ curl https://api.mysite.com/token -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=TestClient&client_secret=TestSecret'
```

You'd get back an access token (like your cookie) and use that on all subsequent calls.

**Implicit Grant Type**

The `Implicit` grant type is similar to the Authorization Code grant type in that it is used to request access to protected resources on behalf of another user (i.e. a 3rd party). It is optimized for public clients, such as those implemented in javascript or on mobile devices, where client credentials cannot be stored.

```
https://api.mysite.com/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=TestClient&redirect_uri=https://myredirecturi.com/cb
```

Source : http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/grant-types/client-credentials/